# PHP Regular expression, cant figure out whats wrong my expression

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to match few html tags using PHP's preg_match function. Please tell me is this expression correct.

```
$keyword = "keyword";

$contents = "some random keyword some random keyword some random keyword some random 
keyword some random keyword some random keyword some random keyword some random keyword 
some random keyword some random keyword some random keyword some random keyword some  
random keyword some random keyword some random <strong>keyword</strong> some 
random keyword some random keyword some random keyword 
some random keyword some random keyword some random keyword  ";

 $seo_pattern = "/<strong>{1}keyword{1}</strong>{1}/";

if(preg_match($seo_pattern, $contents)){
echo "<br>Match found :)";
}else{
echo "<br>No match found!";
}
```

I am not getting any matches ? :(

Comment: Don't parse html with regex, use an html parser.

Comment: ... because `<strong class="important">keyword</strong>` and `<span class="strong">keyword</span>` and `<string><b>keyword</b></strong>` etc...

Comment: The code is giving error (PHP Warning:  preg_match(): Unknown modifier 't' in ...). You didn't notice it?

Comment: what is HTML parser ? Please shed some light on this topic. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Escape the slash

```
$seo_pattern = "/<strong>keyword<\/strong>/";
                          here __^
```

Comment: Thanks man, this solved the problem. I was going crazy because the expression worked fine in .net lol

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why you use {1}. What it does is it tells that the character or group before the {1} must only match one time, but if you don't specifiy it at all, it will match only one time anyway.

Then you use / as a regex delimiter, and you also use the / in the regex, that's not gonna work. You can either change your regex delimiter or backslash the slash.

Other delimiter:

```
#<strong>keyword</strong>#
```

Escape slash:

```
/<strong>keyword<\/strong>/
```

Comment: Thankyou  adding this "\" before "/" solved the problem. I use {1} because I am looking for a keyword that has to appear only once between the HTML tags.

Comment: It already matches only one time, and if you are talking about the whole keyword then you should use: (?:keyword){1} because otherwise the {1} only works on the previous character (the 'd'). But then still, {1} is not needed because it matches only one time by default.

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the `/`:

```
$seo_pattern = "/<strong>{1}keyword{1}<\/strong>{1}/";
```